# command failed with attributedString in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement af attributedString into a UILabel, but i keep getting following error. `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault 11`. i'm btw using xcode 8 beta and swift 3.0.

```
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleText, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 14)])

    let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium ", size: 14)]

    // Part of string to be bold
    attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: titleText.rangeOfString("Anytime. Anywhere."))



    introTextLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Which line causes the segfault? (And which beta seed is this?)

Comment: when i remove `attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: titleText.rangeOfString("Anytime. Anywhere."))` it seem to build properly

Comment: is it maybe just the space in `Avenir-Medium ` that makes the font initialization fail? I am confused though since the `UIFont` object has to be unwrapped in your first line, hasn't it? and also the `titleText` property is kinda mixed. in the first line a swift `String` is expected. in the third line a `NSRange` is expected. but the `rangeOfString` method returns a `Range<Index>`...

Answer (score 1):

as a follow up to my comment on your original post this is what works for me (where `titleText` is a swift string):

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleText, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 14)!])

let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 14)!]

// Part of string to be bold
attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: (titleText as NSString).range(of: "Anytime. Anywhere."))

introTextLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```